# Render custom auto complete results

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have the following code:

```
jQuery("#hotelName").autocomplete({
            serviceUrl:'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            minChars:1,
            delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/, // regex or character
            maxHeight:200,
            zIndex: 9999,
            appendTo: "#ui-front"
         }).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                console.log(item);
              return jQuery( "<li>" )
                .data( "ui-autocomplete-item", item )
                .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul );
            };
```

I'm getting this error from console:

```
Cannot set property '_renderItem' of undefined
```

I'm using `jQuery UI Auto complete 1.2.9`

Auto complete is working without any problem like this :

```
jQuery("#hotelName").autocomplete({
                serviceUrl:'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                minChars:1,
                delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/, // regex or character
                maxHeight:200,
                zIndex: 9999,
                appendTo: "#ui-front"
             });
```

But I want to apply custom rendering. Any idea what is the problem?

**EDIT:**

I tried to upgrade jQuery UI Auto Complete to the latest version but that didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the widget instance (which `_renderItem` property you want to adjust) from a jQuery object wrapping the element having this widget applied, you should use [**instance()**](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-instance) method of the widget, as shown in [**the docs**](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data). For example:

```
$('#input_to_autocomplete')
  .autocomplete(widgetOptions) // applying the widget
  .autocomplete('instance')    // getting the widget's instance
  ._renderItem = function(ul, item) { /*... */ }; // augmenting the display function
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I changed the code and I'm not getting any errors in console which is good so far and auto complete is working but items aren't rendering as expected, also I'm not getting any thing on console regarding to this `console.log(item);`

Comment: @SzamDev That makes little sense to me, to be honest. Can you prepare the fiddle demonstrating what you have there?

Comment: @SzamDev Works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vv2dwxLb/), the original was a slew of errors (that you'd have checked).

Comment: Thank you very much, everything is clear now. I just noticed that you upgraded jQuery to 2.1.0 Is that necessary?

Comment: @SzamDev No, it's not necessary; `jQuery UI 1.11` requires `jQuery 1.6+`.